# MCP3201 ADC timing clarifications

Tags: adc, spi, timing

I'm trying to understand the timing for the SPI analog to digital converter MCP3201 by Microchip.

What I understand is that I can clock it up to 1.6MHz, and the conversion takes 12 clock cycles. 
So that should mean that the conversion, at that clock speed, takes (0.625uS * 12) = 7.5uS.

But then, how long does it takes to trasmit the data to the microcontroller?

The maximum ksps spec (100ksps) seems to indicate that the fastest conversion/acquisition that we can do takes 16 cycles (1.6MHz/100Ksps), so 10uS.

I may be totally wrong on that.

But if I'm right, then why the 2.5uS gap (10uS - 7.5uS)?
To be conservative, or because that extra 4 cycles are needed to trasmit data to the microcontroller?
Or other reasons?

There is a timing diagram (of course) on the datasheet that should give me the reply, but since I'm not an engineer I have some difficulty to fully understand it.

Link:
http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP3201

Datasheet:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21290F.pdf

thank you
Dimitri

Answer (score 2):

The data is clocked out, MSB first, simultaneously with the ADC converting the input. A Successive Approximation Converter (SAR) evaluates the MSB, then the next, and so on down the the LSB. Each bit is spat out as soon as it's ready, so the conversion is complete by the time the whole word has been clocked out.

That's the fastest way to use the part. If you want LSB first data, you have to wait while it converts it MSB first, then keep clocking and it will spit out the data the other way round. That however slows the part down to about half the MSB-first speed.

Comment: thank you, so if I understand well, also by looking at the Figure 1.1 on the datasheet, the time between the start of two successive conversions can't be less than tSUCS + 12 cycles + tCSH.
but why immediately after tSUCS there seems to be a half-cycle? and why they only specify min. time for tSUCS and tCSH?

Comment: tSUCHS is measured to the first rising edge, whether clock was high or low before CS went active low, that's not a half cycle, just showing that optional level, or the falling edge of CLK being ignored. There are only minimum timings for those because they can be any large time you like. This is a static converter, it doesn't need a continuously running clock. When you want a conversion, pull CS and clock 16 times. It appears to be the first rising edge after CS that latches the input analogue voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Some extra time is required for an analog sample to be taken, after the conversion begins by chip-select (CS) going low, and SPI clocking begins. So a complete 12-bit conversion requires a few more than 12 clock cycles. The analog sample is captured during the first two SPI clock cycles.

A problem to be overcome is that SPI communication usually works in 8-bit "chunks". So to get a **complete** 12-bit conversion, two 8-bit chunks must be transmitted, requiring 16 clocks. The first chunk contains the five most-significant bits, and the last chunk contains seven least-significant bits. Then some software is required to concatenate the two chunks together to get a 12-bit result. Sixteen clocks at 1.6 MHz gives data rate of 100 kSamples/sec.
See page 15 of the microchip datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

ADCs that share the GND with analog input and analog-comparator and digital input/output have risks with rail-bouncing issues.

ADCs, in concurrently implementing the internal analog comparator decision, and in clocking out data, will be VULNERABLE to digital noise trashing the analog ground.

To minimize trashing the analog decision, use SLOW edges on the clock. And experiment with various duty cycles. If comparator decision is clocked at same time as data_out is updated, you may be safe. Or not.

To minimize currents demanded by Data_out, use 1Kohm or even higher, located directly at the ADC Data_out pin.

FIgure 2-29, near the 1MHz region, suggests the SNR falls to 40dB (6 bits ENOB) because of trash on the rails. Fast clock edges will trash the rails.

---

Here is what a chip looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftnsZQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The internal well contacts and substrate contacts, individually, are high resistance and thus excellent dampeners for VDD/GND ringing. A massive amount of both creates LOW resistance and thus poor dampening.

That BLUE outside loop should be avoided; its Fring will be low, and hard to dampen. And the analog comparator likely has poor PSRR at Fring.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but does that mean that clocking the SPI bus too fast would reduce the effective number of bits? figure 2-29 looks to me like something related to power supply ripple frequency, or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Ya know, that's informative, but not especially helpful in explaining the timing of the spi signal.

Comment: Yes-----clocking too fast would put the ENOB at risk. The comparator needs time to decide, the charge-balancing switches need time to slosh the charge around among the onchip binary-approximation capacitors, and VDD/GND/VREF need time to BECOME QUIET.

Answer (score 0):

Here is spectral response of PI resonance, the smaller capacitor (on left) being inside the silicon, the middle inductor being the leadframe/bondwire/vias, and the right capacitor (1uF) being on the PCB. To examine the risk of TWO external caps, I've added another. We see peaks and valleys in the response.[image]

In the above response, the 2nd external cap had only 1milliOhm ESR. Now make that be 50milliOhm ESR.
[image]

We now have 20dB less peaking, energy that would confuse the ADC's analog comparator. And if this "network" were the VREF network, the ADC's demands for charge during the binary-search process would keep the VREF pin bouncing around.

Unless we design the dampening. And unless we use SLOW edges on the SPI signals.